# Complication using file inclusion in PHP: folder levels

Tags: php

I have the following server structure:

```
root
    /folder/inclusion4.php
    /folder/script_to_include.php
    /called_script.php
    /inclusion1.php
    /inclusion2.php
    /inclusion3.php
```

`called_script.php` includes `script_to_include`.

`script_to_include` includes `inclusion 1/2/3/4`.

This generates a lot of inclusion problems due to `../` when writing `include(../inclusionX.php)` because those belong in the same folder as `called_script.php` (`root`).

I was wondering how exactly should I point the root of the server /relative path as the beginning of the path for each inclusion or adapt `called_script.php` in particular to react accordingly.

Comment: tried with `__DIR__` ?

Comment: you can do something like that: 
`$path = array
    (
     get_include_path(),
     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
     realpath('./'),
     );

    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $path));`
and then you can include file without relative paths

Comment: for me , best solution is to include all file with absolute path , or say relative to document root